# How do I stop Windows 7 Update Agent "resuming" even though I've set it to "Never check for updates"?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I observe that the Windows 7 System Log file is repeatedly alternating "Updates resumed" and "Updates paused", a few hours apart, even though I've set "Never check for updates" in "Control Panel"/"Change Settings".

How do I stop the Windows 7 Update Agent from "resuming" when I've already set it to "Never check for updates"?

Comment: If your not running Windows 10, why mention it, your problem isn't connect to it.  The upgrade offer expired 3 months ago, unless you pay for Windows 10 and install it yourself, your machine will NEVER be upgraded to Eindows 10

Comment: What does your question have to do with `ssh`?

Comment: @Seeker - We are not showing your question an, excessive attention to layout/format, we are properly formatting your question so it can be read which will result in an answer.  Is this PC connected to an AD server?

Comment: @Seeker: “AD” stands for Active Directory. Given that you’re talking about a personally-owned standalone PC (in your home?) that you’ve set up and configured, and that you administer, and given that you’re not familiar with the abbreviation “AD”, it’s highly likely that this PC is not connected to an AD server.